# Write unittest and save in the separate folder

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-unittest

I am trying to write a unittest for my class. First of all, i install the package unittest and create a spec folder to save all my unittest files. Then i create a test dart file with following contents:

```dart
library i18n_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {


}
```

When i run the file, i got the following error

```
Unable to open file: D:\Dart\i18n\bin\spec\packages\unittest\unittest.dart'file:///D:/Dart/i18n/bin/spec/i18n_test.dart': error: line 3 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
```

As i mentioned, i saved my unittest file in the spec folder, i think that because the compiler could not find the package unittest.
My Folder structure looks like:
[image]

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by a missing `packages` symlink in your `spec` folder.
see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16947

Anyway
unit tests should be put into the `test` folder (`i18n/test`).
This way your test code won't be included in the build output.

It's best to have most of your code in the `lib` folder to make it easy to import into your tests using package imports like:

```dart
import 'package:i18n/my_dart_file.dart';
```

you should still be able to import from `bin` or `web` using relative imports like

```dart
import '../bin/my_dart_file.dart';
```

but that form is not very refactoring-friendly.

Comment: can you please show me, where i have to place lib folder?

Comment: make `lib` a sibling of `bin` and `test` (`i18n/lib`). see also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html